# How to create main.cpp when using Qt designer?

Tags: c++, qt, designer

I am new to Qt, and I use QT 4.4.3 on Linux.

When I design a new Qt GUI with Qt Designer, is there a way to make it create main.cpp automatically, or do I have to manually create a file and manually add it to the Makefile created by qmake?

Comment: are you using qt creator? if yes, you don't need to worry about managing project manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of QT Designer is a GUI element, essentially a subclass of `QWidget`. It will not generate a `main` function for you (the entry point for the C runtime to locate). You'll have to write your own where you create a `QApplication`, and then instantiate and `show` the main window widget.

For example, when using Qt Creator to create a default GUI project with a Designer-based main window, the designer creates a main window class named `MainWindow`, and Qt Creator also generates a `main.cpp` with these contents:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Where the application (`QApplication`) is defined, the main window is instantiated, and finally the event loop of the application is executed.

---

**Update:** The `.pro` file (suitable for `qmake`'s consumption - [read here about the syntax](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-project-files.html)) generated by Qt Creator for such a basic project is:

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = test1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

You may use this as a basis for your own `.pro` file, should you choose to do this manually instead of via Qt Creator.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Eli's post, you don't add files manually to the makefiles generated by qmake. Instead, you add files to the .pro file (or a .pri file which is included by the .pro file) you run qmake on.

[This link](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/IncludingProFiles) will show you how to add sources to a PRI file and how to include that file in your PRO file.